# Why does my code keep returning 1 with the error message even though I input a digit?

Tags: c, cs50

I am trying to complete the Caesar excercise on pset 2. My code compiles fine however it seems to give me me the output Usage: ./caesar key even though I input an int. Any help is much appreciated on where I am going wrong :)

The program should work whereby the user types ./Caesar followed by a space and an integer. It should print success and the integer given. If the user was to type anything else other than this ie. 2x or any characters etc, it should print
Usage: ./caesar key.

```
// Libraries
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])

{

    if (argc == 2 && (atoi(argv[1]) > 0))
     for(int i = 0, len = strlen(argv[1]); i < len; i++)
        {
           char n = argv[1][i];
           int digit = isdigit(n);


           if (n != digit)
            {
                printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
                return 1;
            }

          else
            {
                printf("Success\n %i", digit);
                return 0;
            }  


        }

    else 
    {
       printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
       return 1; 
    }


}
```

Comment: explain how you call the executable clearly.

Comment: ... that is, please provide a complete example command line.

Comment: @muyustan made it a little clearer, hope this makes more sense ```./Caesar 3```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int digit = isdigit(n);
if (n != digit)
```

should be

```
int digit = isdigit(n);  // 0 (false) if n isn't a digit; non-zero (true) if n is a digit.
if (!digit)
```

or just

```
if (!isdigit(n))
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code returns 1 every time because of the statement

`if(n != digit)`

`isdigit()` function in C returns a non-zero value (1) if the character passed to it is a digit i.e. between 0 to 9.
When you compare `n` and `digit`, then the ascii value of n and digit will be compared. So if condition will always result in True as `n` and `digit` will not be equal.

I guess what you want is to compare is digit is zero i.e.

`if(digit == 0)`

Comment: ... or more conventional would be to skip the `digit` variable altogether, and just write `if (isdigit(n))`.  It even reads more cleanly.

Comment: Re "*Your code returns 1 every time because of the statement*", Unless one or more `0` is provided (although that would be caught by an earlier check).

Comment: `if(digit == 0)` is a weird way of writing `if (!digit)`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger  As suggested Iv'e changed the code but it seems to now not pick up the non numeric characters now as still sees them as digits  

~/Pset2/ $ ./Caesar 34x
Success
 34x
~/Pset2/ $

In theory it should print Usage: ./caesar key and return 1 for a non digit value.

Comment: @Andrewoca, I should have written 'if (!isdigit())`, sorry.  The point is that there is no particular usefulness to storing the function result in an intermediate variable if, as in this case, you're only going to use it once.  There is *documentary* value in some such cases, but here, using an intermediate variable actually makes your code *harder* to read and understand, not easier.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Got it John, Thanks so much for the help!